# Vinkla instagram in Laravel 5.5 and Show some Error

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to integrate vinkla/instagram in Laravel 5.5.

I use php version is 7.0.

But it is showing some error. I tried the following steps:

---

1.Run `composer require vinkla/instagram`

2.Added the service provider to `config/app.php`

```
Vinkla\Instagram\InstagramServiceProvider::class
```

3.Added to `config/app.php` in aliases

```
'Instagram' => Vinkla\Instagram\Facades\Instagram::class
```

4.When I run some command (`php artisan vendor:publish`,`composer dump-autoload`,`php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear`),it shows the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU7jO.png)

```
 Class 'Vinkla\Instagram\InstagramServiceProvider' not found.
```

---

How can I solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into the [vinkla/instagram](https://github.com/vinkla/instagram) package and I don't see the `InstagramServiceProvider` on the latest few versions (latest version at this time is [7.0.0](https://github.com/vinkla/instagram/tree/7.0.0))

Latest version that has `InstagramServiceProvider` file (and that supports Laravel) is [4.2.0](https://github.com/vinkla/instagram/tree/4.2.0)

You can install that version by running

`composer require vinkla/instagram:4.2.0`

---

Update:

I tested with 7.0.0 version of [vinkla/instagram](https://github.com/vinkla/instagram)

```
composer require vinkla/instagram
```

This would give you instagram feed for user "jerryseinfeld"

```
Route::get('instagram', function(Request $request) {
  // Create a new instagram instance.
  $instagram = new \Vinkla\Instagram\Instagram();

  // Fetch the media feed.
  $feed      = $instagram->get('jerryseinfeld');

  // return json
  return $feed;
});
```

With version 7.0.0 you need to remove

service provider

```
Vinkla\Instagram\InstagramServiceProvider::class
```

and alias

```
'Instagram' => Vinkla\Instagram\Facades\Instagram::class
```

from `config/app.php`

Answer (score 1):

Please note as of version 8.0.0 Public feed was removed [Link](https://github.com/vinkla/instagram/releases/tag/8.0.0)